# How to edit GCP Cloud Run add mapping to /etc/hosts

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I need to map a service name to an IP in order the make an application to work
/etc/host file example:

```
10.0.0.1 service-name
```

But trying to edit that file during Dockerfile build it throws me a

```
/bin/sh: can't create /etc/hosts: Read-only file system
```

In the GCP Cloud Run YAML there is no support for "HostAliases"
I can't add the "--add-host" flag in GCP Cloud Run

Does anyone know any other option to be able to map a service-name to an specific IP to fix my Cloud Run App?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

VOLUME /tmp
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .

# This are the lines that are not working
# And can't find any workaround in GCP Cloud Run
RUN echo 10.0.0.4   servicename-0 >> /etc/hosts
RUN echo 10.0.0.3   servicename-1 >> /etc/hosts

EXPOSE 3000
ARG NODE_ENV=production
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

Comment: Show your Dockerfile and the hosts file.

Comment: Is it internal service? Not Cloud Run services right?

Comment: Yes, the service-name is an internal service, cloud run can access it thru VPC but can't resolve the internal service-name, and I don't have access to change the app to not use the service-name or make it configurable with ENV variables

Comment: One idea is to add **dnsmasq** to your container.